# Access local apache virtualhost on Android (same network)

Tags: android, apache, virtualhost, vhosts, hosts

I have a computer and an S3 on the same wifi network, the computer has apache running with VirtualHost for http://example.local, along with a few others. This all works fine from the computer. Computer IP is 10.0.0.2

The phone is rooted, I appended `10.0.0.2 example.local www.example.local` to /system/etc/hosts and it couldn't find the domain, even though ping worked. I tried some SO solutions to this but none fixed it, so instead I removed default `hosts` file and kept the top line as my `10.0.0.2` definition. This now connects to my machine in browser, but it just loads the `localhost` vhost config, instead of the `example.local` one.

`httpd-vhosts.conf` on computer

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    ServerAdmin tom.corby@tastecard.co.uk
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.example.local:80>
    ServerAdmin tom.corby@tastecard.co.uk
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/www.example.co.uk/branches/release/3.4/www/"
    ServerName www.example.local
    ServerAlias example.local
    ErrorLog "logs/www.example.local.log"
    CustomLog "logs/www.example.local.log" common

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/www.example.co.uk/branches/release/3.4/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Like I say this loads fine on the computer, and I can load `localhost` for my xampp/htdocs directory, or example.local for the deeper project directory. All I ever get on android is `localhost` directory

Answer (score 0):

VirtualHost was configured incorrectly so it was defaulting back to the default `localhost` vhost (This may be why the URLs are showing up in red on SO? Should have been a warning to me really)

Instead of having URL defined in `<VirtualHost>` element, just leave it as `*:80` and it all works again. Not sure why the computer was okay with this but android not.